# passing data from javascript to django view when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, django, file-upload

I created a `no javascript` code which uses an `html form` and `django view` to upload a file .It uses an `html5 input` element for selecting the file.On clicking the `submit` button,the file gets uploaded without any problem.The django view can get the file from `request.FILES`

```
def upload_file(request,template_name):
    to_return = {}
    store_message="failure"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES.has_key('fselect'):
            file = request.FILES['fselect']
            with open('/uploadpath/%s' % file.name, 'wb+') as dest:
                for chunk in file.chunks():
                    dest.write(chunk)
            store_message="success"
    to_return['store_message']= store_message
    if store_message == "failure":
        return redirect('home')
    reqctx = RequestContext(request,to_return)
    return return render_to_response(template_name,reqctx)
```

the html form is

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{% url uploaded %}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="fselect" id="fselect">    </input>
    <input type="submit" id="uploadbtn" value="upload">    
    </form>
```

Now I want to use some `javascript` to call the `django` view .
I have coded ajax version of upload view

```
def ajax_upload_file(request):
    to_return = {}
    store_message="failure"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES.has_key('fselect'):
            file = request.FILES['fselect']
            with open('/uploadpath/%s' % file.name, 'wb+') as dest:
                for chunk in file.chunks():
                    dest.write(chunk)
            store_message="success"
     to_return['store_message']= store_message
     serialized = simplejson.dumps(to_return)
     if store_message == "failure":
        return HttpResponseServerError(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
     else:
        return HttpResponse(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
```

I am confused about how the `file` object can be passed from `javascript` code to django view.

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fselect').change(function(){uploadFile()});

}
function uploadSubTitleFile(){
    //check if it is a subtitle file?
    var file=document.getElementById('fselect').files[0];
    var data = {  };//how to pass the data
    var args = { type:"POST", url:"ajax_upload/", data:data, complete:done };    
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple answer, you don't. Send your form into an hidden iframe and and let the javascript call its parent window.

> Since file uploading occurs through an iframe, traditional response data such as HTTP status codes are not directly available, and connection manager cannot reasonably discern success or failure (except a transaction timeout). Instead, the callback's upload handler will receive a response object containing the body of the iframe document, as a string, when the transaction is complete.
>
> — http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/#upload

My advise is, find a decent library that does that for you and use it:

- https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader
- http://www.uploadify.com/
- …

With recent browsers, it's possible to do it without relying on an iframe: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)